# Why I don't have span argument in Lazy Grid item() in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

The link is the image that contains the layout diagram I want to output using the Lazy Vertical Grid in jetpack compose. However, I don't know why I don't have a span argument in my item()/items() inside the LazyVerticalGrid.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JpON.png)

Here is my code,

```
LazyVerticalGrid(
    cells = GridCells.Fixed(2),
    modifier = Modifier
        .background(Color.Black)
        .padding(start = 20.dp, end = 20.dp, top = 20.dp),
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(20.dp),
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(20.dp),
    content = {

        item (span = {
            GridItemSpan(maxLineSpan)
        }) {
            //Text header
        }

    }
)
```

}

Error: "Cannot find the parameter with this name: span"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things you can check:

Make sure you have a current compose version.
The [releasenotes](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-foundation#1.1.0-beta03) seem to indicate you need at least Version 1.1.0-beta03

Make sure you have the correct imports. (You might have imported the list version etc.)

```
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.grid.GridItemSpan
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.grid.items
```

Comment: Updating the compose version solved my problem. Thank you so much !!

Comment: Btw: Compose is moving FAST. It's often a good idea to update to new major stable versions if possible